# PHP without color/style error messages

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error

I dont know why, but my php is showing the error messages without style,

**My PHP errors right now**
[image: My PHP]

**How should be**
[image: How Should be]

**Can u help me?**
Sorry my english sucks.

(Those images are only examples)
(My system is ubuntu)

Comment: Those erros in orange tables are from WAMP server in Windows :/

Comment: That sucks, i wanna orange errors on linux too.

Answer (score 1):

Formatted error messages are not built in to php.

The screenshot you give is from a framework or project that has spent time and effort formatting error messages. You can either roll your own or take the code from that project to format your own messages.

Answer (score 0):

Install [xDebug](https://xdebug.org/), that's the extension you are missing. WAMP and XAMPP comes preinstall with it, or you can try other debugging tools like [PHP Debug Bar](https://github.com/maximebf/php-debugbar) and others, Google is your friend. Cheers.